# Problemar en switch Java lanzando mensaje de error

Tags: java, array

Estoy haciendo un ejercicio de un programa para reservar entradas, el programa se considera un prototipo en el que sólo hay 12 entradas a la venta.
Cada vez que alguien hace una reserva se le pide su dni y el nº entradas a reservar, el máximo por persona es 4 y pueden llegar al máximo en una o varias reservas. Suponemos que no habrá anulaciones y que los clientes introducen bien los datos.
El programa ha de llevar dos arrays, el 1 guarda los dnis y el 2, en la misma celda, guarda las entradas correspondientes al dni, estos arrays son de 12 celdas. Cada cliente está identificado por un dni y solo ocupa una celda aunque haga varias peticiones.

Bien, tengo el programa casi listo a excepción de que cuando introduzco 5 entradas debería darme un error del tipo "No puedes reservas más de 5 entradas" y lo que hace es darme el error pero aún así permite al cliente comprar las entradas.

¿Alguien puede echarme una mano?

Indicar que soy muy novato y no tengo permitido (estudios) ni usar length ni otras cosas por el estilo. Básicamente el código ha de moverse en el nivel de lo que veréis a continuación.

Una vez más, gracias.

```
//variables
int dni=0, opc, usuario=0, entradas=0, cuentausu=0, dimentradas=0, disponibles=12;
boolean cliente=false;

//Array que contendrá los dni
int arr1 [];
arr1 = new int[12];

//Array que contendrá las reservas
int arr2 [];
arr2=new int[12];

//Menú de selección, va en un bucle hasta que pulsen salir
do {
    Scanner entradaTeclado=new Scanner(System.in);

    System.out.println("Bienvenido a Genaro, su asistente virtual para la reserva de entradas.");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("1-Reservar entradas.");
    System.out.println("2-Consultar cuantas entradas hay disponibles.");
    System.out.println("3-Salir del programa.");
    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Por favor, seleccione una de las opciones anteriores: ");
    opc=entradaTeclado.nextInt();

    switch (opc){
        case 1:   
            // Pedimos DNI al usuario.
            System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca su DNI :");
            dni = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

            //For para recorrer el array.
            for (int x=0; x<12; x++){     
                //comprobamos si es cliente y si no lo guardo.
                if(arr1[x] == dni){
                    usuario=x;       
                    //Guardo el nº de entradas en el segundo array en la misma posicion que el dni.
                    entradas=arr2[x];

                    //Bandera de control para ver si es cliente.
                    cliente=true;
                }
            }

            //Metemos usuario si no es cliente y un nuevo usuario si tiene cero entradas.
            if (cliente == false){
                arr1[cuentausu]=dni;
                arr2[cuentausu]=0;
                usuario=cuentausu;
                entradas = 0;
                cuentausu++;
            }

            //Mensaje de aviso si tiene 4 o más entradas.
            if (entradas>=4){
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Ha reservado el máximo de entradas por persona, muchas gracias por confiar en Genaro.");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            }

            //Informamos cuantas entradas puede comprar
            else  {
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Cuantas entradas quiere comprar, llevas "+entradas+" compradas de un máximo de 4. Quedan " +disponibles+ " entradas disponibles");
                dimentradas=entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Ha comprado " +dimentradas+ " entradas, muchas gracias por confiar en Genaro, su asistente virtual para la reserva de tickets.");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");        
                //Informamos de que ha solicitado demasiadas entradas y las que tiene compradas.
                while (arr2[usuario]>dimentradas || disponibles<dimentradas ){
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Disculpa, solo puedes comprar un máximo 4 entradas");
                    System.out.println("Cuantas entradas quiere comprar, llevas "+arr2[usuario]+" ");
                    dimentradas=entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                }
                //Se suman las entradas solicitadas a las que ya hubiese.
                arr2[usuario]=arr2[usuario]+dimentradas;
                disponibles=disponibles-dimentradas;
            }
            cliente=false;
            //Cerramos el case 1
            break;

        //Opción dos del programa (consulta de entradas disponibles y de reserva)
        case 2:
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
            System.out.println("Hay un total de " +disponibles+ " entradas");
            System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    } 
//Opción para salir del programa. 
}  while (opc!=3);
```

Comment: Es que no estás comprobando el límite de 5 en ninguna parte, así que es imposible que haga lo que quieres. Una vez introduce las que quiere comprar, el while comprueba que las que ya ha comprado sea mayor que las que acaba de pedir¿?¿? o que las que hay en total (12) sea menor que las que ha pedido comprar. Dale otra vuelta a esta condición porque no haces referencia al tope de 5 en ninguna parte.

Comment: Mil gracias SuperG280! :)

Comment: @SuperG280 agrega tu comentario como respuesta ya que este solucionó el problema. Así podrás ganar reputación.

Comment: @Moucho me parece que tienes varios detalles, veo que no estas obteniendo la cantidad de entradas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El menú principal lo tienes dentro del bucle, podrías agregarlo como otra opción, opción 0 y de esta forma controlar su llamado.

Al terminar cada opción define `opc = 0` y llama `break;` para provocar que cargue nuevamente el menú principal.

Puedes agregar la validación para comprar hasta 4 entradas en tu while.

Revisa los cambios a tu código (se hace uso de `length` solo para que se muestren los datos y compruebes la salida) :

```
   //variables
    int dni = 0, opc = 0, usuario = 0, entradas = 0, cuentausu = 0, dimentradas = 0, disponibles = 12;
    boolean cliente = false;
    //Array que contendrá los dni
    int arr1[];
    arr1 = new int[12];

    //Array que contendrá las reservas
    int arr2[];
    arr2 = new int[12];

    Scanner entradaTeclado = new Scanner(System.in);

    //Menú de selección, va en un bucle hasta que pulsen salir
    do {

        switch (opc) {

            case 0: //Menu principal

                System.out.println("Bienvenido a Genaro, su asistente virtual para la reserva de entradas.");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("1-Reservar entradas.");
                System.out.println("2-Consultar cuantas entradas hay disponibles.");
                System.out.println("3-Salir del programa.");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Por favor, seleccione una de las opciones anteriores: ");
                opc = entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                if(opc>3){//Evita recibir una opción no existente, envia al menu principal.
                  opc=0;
                }
                break;

            case 1:

                //Pedimos DNI al usuario.
                System.out.println("Por favor, introduzca su DNI :");
                dni = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

                //For para recorrer el array.
                for (int x = 0; x < 12; x++) {

                    //comprobamos si es cliente y si no lo guardo.
                    if (arr1[x] == dni) {
                        usuario = x;
                        //Guardo el nº de entradas en el segundo array en la misma posicion que el dni.
                        entradas = arr2[x];

                        //Bandera de control para ver si es cliente.
                        cliente = true;
                    }
                }

                //Metemos usuario si no es cliente y un nuevo usuario si tiene cero entradas.
                if (cliente == false) {
                    arr1[cuentausu] = dni;
                    arr2[cuentausu] = 0;
                    usuario = cuentausu;
                    entradas = 0;
                    cuentausu++;
                }

                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Cuantas entradas quiere comprar, llevas " + entradas + " compradas de un máximo de 4. Quedan " + disponibles + " entradas disponibles");
                dimentradas = entradaTeclado.nextInt();

                //Informamos de que ha solicitado demasiadas entradas y las que tiene compradas.
                //while (arr2[usuario] > dimentradas || disponibles < dimentradas) {
                while (dimentradas >= 4 || arr2[usuario] > dimentradas || disponibles < dimentradas) {
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                    System.out.println("Disculpa, solo puedes comprar un máximo 4 entradas");
                    System.out.println("Cuantas entradas quiere comprar, llevas " + arr2[usuario] + " ");
                    dimentradas = entradaTeclado.nextInt();
                    System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                }

                //Se suman las entradas solicitadas a las que ya hubiese.
                arr2[usuario] = arr2[usuario] + dimentradas;
                disponibles = disponibles - dimentradas;

                cliente = false;
                //Cerramos el case 1
                opc = 0; //Va a menu principal.
                break;

            //Opción dos del programa (consulta de entradas disponibles y de reserva)
            case 2:

                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                System.out.println("Hay un total de " + disponibles + " entradas disponibles");
                //Imprime DNIs y sus reservas.
                for (int i = 0; i < arr1.length; i++) {
                    System.out.println("Usuario DNI : " + arr1[i] + " tiene reservadas " + arr2[i] + " entradas.");
                }
                //System.out.println("Hay un total de " + disponibles + " entradas disponibles");
                System.out.println("----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------");
                opc = 0; //Va a menu principal.
                break;
        }

     //Opción para salir del programa. 
    } while (opc != 3);
```

Ejemplo salida:

```
Hay un total de 0 entradas disponibles
Usuario DNI : 1212 tiene reservadas 2 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1214 tiene reservadas 1 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1215 tiene reservadas 1 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1216 tiene reservadas 3 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1217 tiene reservadas 1 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1218 tiene reservadas 3 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 1219 tiene reservadas 1 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 0 tiene reservadas 0 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 0 tiene reservadas 0 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 0 tiene reservadas 0 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 0 tiene reservadas 0 entradas.
Usuario DNI : 0 tiene reservadas 0 entradas.
```

Comment: Madre mía, es una maravilla así, mil gracias!!!!! Lo voy a revisar ahora mismo!